Does conditioning on multiple independent criteria increases the expected value of the common factor?
I'm trying to tackle something related to my economics thesis.
I Have a model with $A∼N(0,1)$, workers permanent ability. $ε_1,ε_2 ~ N(0,1)$, "noise" to workers ability. $A,ε_1,ε_2$ are independent.
In each period $(t)$ workers are promoted from the easy to hard job (there are only two jobs) if $\hat At = A+εt > A^*$. At $t=1$ all of the workers are in the easy job, meaning:
in $t=2$, workers in the hard job are those who for them: $A+ε_1 > A^*$. Here comes the twist, the firm can depromote workers from the hard to the easy job: at $t=3$ workers in the hard job are only those who for them $(A+ε_1>A^*)^{(A+ε_2>A^*)}$.
Looking at the same cohort of workers, I'm trying to prove that the expected value of workers in the hard job in $t=3$ is bigger than workers in the hard job in $t=3$, so:
$$\mathrm E \left[A\middle|(A+ε_1>A^*)^{(A+ε_2>A^*)}\right] > E[A|(A+ε_1>A^*)]$$
Is this true? am I missing something? tried many many times to prove it using hazard rates and what's not.
Thanks!
